# How can I change css from php side?

Tags: javascript, php

Basically, I want to add an additional class when a certain IF condition is met.

```
<?php
    if($type == 'NEW')
    {   
        $('#'+day+s).addClass('new');
    }
    if($type == 'USED')
    {
        $('#'+day+s).addClass('used');
    }
?>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you using it in script?

Comment: After the page loads? Then you need to make an ajax call back to the server to do so. If it's before the page loads, then you just manipulate the html that you are generating. You can also pass the type variable to the client on load and have the class added after checking the variable, but it's still messy. Really you either need to do it all on the server or all on the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to do it through JavaScript / jQuery inside of a PHP conditional.

You can either close your PHP tags while leaving the conditional open:

```
<?php
    if($type == 'NEW')
    {
?>
      <script>$('#'+day+s).addClass('new');</script>
<?php
    }
    if($type == 'USED')
    {
?>
      <script>$('#'+day+s).addClass('used');</script>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Or **[`echo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)** out the `<script>` tags from within PHP:

```
<?php
    if($type == 'NEW')
    {
      echo "<script>$('#'+day+s).addClass('new');</script>";
    }
    if($type == 'USED')
    {
      echo "<script>$('#'+day+s).addClass('used');</script>";
    }
?>
```

Having said that, you'd be better off simply altering your logic to output **classes** based on your conditionals. That way you would simply need to add a regular CSS rule for each class. The right rule would be selected based on which class was outputted.

Answer (score 0):

It should be directly in your HTML :

```
<div class="<?php if ($type == 'NEW') echo 'new';?>"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign your calss name in a variable and simply give that to your corresponding MHTL.

```
<?php
if($type == 'NEW')
{   
    $style           = "class_name for if"; //eg:- new
}
if($type == 'USED')
{
   $style           = "class_name for else"; //eg:- used
}
?>
   //html element
 for eg:
 <p id="days" class="<?php echo $style;?>"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

several ways to do that and depends also in your code

```
<!-- Assignment inline -->
<div class="<?= $type === 'NEW' ? 'newClass' : 'usedClass'?>"></div>

<!-- Assignment previous -->
<?php 
  $class = 'defaultClass';
  if ($type === 'NEW') { $class = 'newClass'; }
  if ($type === 'USED') { $class = 'usedClass'; }
?>
<div class="<?=$class?>"></div>

<!-- Assignment in script -->
<?php $class = $type === 'NEW' ? 'newClass' : 'usedClass'; ?>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('#'+day+s).addClass('<?= $class ?>');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the if condition of PHP inside class attribute directly. No need to do any method or js for this. You can use the logic as below:

```
<div class="<?php if($type == 'NEW'){ echo 'new';} else if($type == 'USED'){ echo 'used'; } ?>"></div>
```